# Azure backup vs Snapshots

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm an azure newbie and just trying to understand Azure better. My questions are specific to backing up Linux VMs in Azure. Please help me in understanding it better.

I read that Azure backup takes snapshots and then uploads them to the vault. I'm trying to understand how using 'Azure backup' to backup a VM is different from taking the snapshots of OS Disk and data disk of azure VM via "az vm" cli commands?

What exactly is the vault here? Is it internally implemented as a storage account with blob container or is it something similar to the Glacier in AWS?

Which is better cost wise, azure backup or osdisk snapshots?

If both the options are similar, i.e using azure backup or taking a snapshot of OS disk/Data disks. Is there an advantage of using one over the other?

Are the Snapshots of OS disk taken in Azure, global in nature or are they in any way associated with a region? If a region is down, do they become unavailable?

In the azure portal, snapshots, what is "snapshot state"? Why is the snapshot state "Unattached" for me even after spinning off a VM from the snapshot disk?

Comment: In general, a backup is for the purposes of disaster recovery and a snapshot is used for change control. If the server suddenly disappears into the ether, you restore from a backup. If you make a change on the server and need to revert, you go to a snapshot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I read that Azure backup takes snapshots and then uploads them to the
>   vault.

You are right, Azure backup will take snapshots first, then upload them to backup vault.

> how using 'Azure backup' to backup a VM is different from taking the
>   snapshots of OS Disk and data disk of azure VM via "az vm" cli
>   commands?

The biggest difference is that, we can use Azure Backup to **restore** VM directly. If we use snapshot and want to restore VM, we have to use snapshot to create OSdisk and then use this OSdisk to create new VM.

By the way, we can set backup jobs in Azure Backup, so Azure can run backup by **backup policy**. If we use snapshot, we should do it manually.

> What exactly is the vault here?

The vault same as storage account, but we can't find it in our portal, and can't migrate backup data, we can manage the vault via Azure Backup.

> Which is better cost wise, azure backup or osdisk snapshots?

For now, we can use CLI 2.0 command `az snapshot create` to create snapshot, but we can't use this to snapshot some on-prem resource.

If we just want on-time backup of Azure VM, and we can use PowerShell to restore it, I guess we can use snapshot.

If we want to daily backup of VM, I think we should use Azure Backup.

About cost, Azure backup and snapshot charge for the usage of storage account.

> using azure backup or taking a snapshot of OS disk/Data disks. Is
>   there an advantage of using one over the other?

In my opinion, take snapshot used for restore VM to one time, for example, I want to do some configure change, before that I take a snapshot of it, then change the configure, if it false I can restore VM with the snapshot.

> Are the Snapshots of OS disk taken in Azure, global in nature or are
>   they in any way associated with a region? If a region is down, do they
>   become unavailable?

we can choose SKU for snapshot, Premium_LRS, Standard_LRS. so you are right, if the region is down, the snapshot will **unavailable**.

> In the azure portal, snapshots, what is "snapshot state"? Why is the
>   snapshot state "Unattached" for me even after spinning off a VM from
>   the snapshot disk?

We can't attach the snapshot to Azure VM, so the state is unattached.
I have create a disk from the snapshot, and the state is unattached.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: How do I use the snapshot to restore VM? I've scoured the Internet for a while now so my google-foo needs some help.

Answer (score 0):

how using 'Azure backup' to backup a VM is different from taking the snapshots of OS Disk and data disk of azure VM via "az vm" cli commands?

The biggest difference is that, we can use Azure Backup to restore VM directly. If we use snapshot and want to restore VM, we have to use snapshot to create OSdisk and then use this OSdisk to create new VM.

///Also, those snapshot can be attach to existing VM (DataDisks), for OsDisk, disk swapon is the option thru snapshot method